# Android MediaController VideoView - Always appears when loading, although not properly tab

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a tablayout with different tabs, including the tab displaying the video list. In the video tab, I use videoview to display video and set mediacontroller for it.

Result:

[image]

But when I go to another activity, then back to the old activity. The mediacontroller automatically pops up even though I'm standing at the text tab, not the video tab

[image]

Can you show me how to just show mediacontroller in tabvideo, stop showing anywhere like that?

Well, I use recyclerview to display the video list, and this is my adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    VideoModel item = VideoList.get(position);
    ((VHItem) holder).tvTittle.setText(item.getVideoTittle());
    ((VHItem) holder).tvTime.setText(item.getVideoTime());
    /***get clicked view and play video url at this position**/
    try {
        //play video using android api, when video view is clicked.
        String url = item.getVideoUrl(); // your URL here
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        //((VHItem) holder).videoView.seekTo(10);
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                        /*
                         * add media controller
                         */
                        MediaController mc = new MediaController(mContext);
                        mc.setMediaPlayer(((VHItem) holder).videoView);
                        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setMediaController(mc);
                        /*
                         * and set its position on screen
                         */
                        mc.setAnchorView(((VHItem) holder).videoView);



                    }
                });

                ((VHItem) holder).videoView.seekTo(10);
            }
        });


    } catch (
            Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I think the problem lies in `setOnPreparedListener` correct?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

1.setAnchorView() uses parent of VideoView to overlay the media controls. If you have a video with fixed height make sure you put it inside a framelayout so that media controls are on top of the video.
2.The problem may be you only use `setAnchorView()` inside your `setOnVideoSizeChangedListener` .Try something like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    VideoModel item = VideoList.get(position);
    ((VHItem) holder).tvTittle.setText(item.getVideoTittle());
    ((VHItem) holder).tvTime.setText(item.getVideoTime());
    /***get clicked view and play video url at this position**/
    try {
        //play video using android api, when video view is clicked.
        String url = item.getVideoUrl(); // your URL here
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        //((VHItem) holder).videoView.seekTo(10);
         if (mc == null) {//declare a private variable like "  private MediaController mc;" in the beginning of your adapter class
        mc = new MediaController(mContex);
         mc.setAnchorView(((VHItem) holder).videoView);
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setMediaController(mc);                                                                           
         }              
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {


                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {



                        mc.setAnchorView(((VHItem) holder).videoView);



                    }
                });

                ((VHItem) holder).videoView.seekTo(10);
            }
        });


    } catch (
            Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(contex);
    MediaController controller=new MediaController(this);
    videoHolder.setMediaController(controller);

    controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Above code will hide your MediaController.

Comment: The question is differ from your answer